# when using "ionic start" whats the difference between "ionic-angular" and "ionic1" types?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im reading the ionic cli docs and i see some "type" options that i dont know how they differ.. can someone give me some light on this?

```
$ ionic start mynewapp tabs --type ionic-angular
$ ionic start mynewapp blank --type ionic1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ ionic start mynewapp tabs --type ionic-angular
```

will  `start` a new `ionic` app, in a folder named `mynewapp`, using the `tabs` template and will be based on the **latest** `ionic` (currently v3.4) and `angular` (currently 4.2).

```
$ ionic start mynewapp blank --type ionic1
```

will  `start` a new `ionic` app, in a folder named `mynewapp`, using the `blank` template (e.g. hellow world) and will be based on the **legacy** `ionic v 1.*` and `angularjs v1.*`.

In any case, when in doubt omit the `type` flag entirely (defaults to using the latest version) unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I hope this covers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, so you would say that use "--type ionic-angular" and not using type is the same thing??

Comment: Yes. Give it a try yourself.